# Function returns 'undefined' value

Tags: javascript, function, return-value, alert

I have this code below:

```
alert('Returned value : ' + myid_templates_editor_image_id_generator());


//Generates unique id for every image created
function myid_templates_editor_image_id_generator(){    
    (function($){
        var a = 1;
        while(true){                    
            if($('#myid_templates_editor_image_' + a).length == 0) {                
                alert('Inside value : ' a);
                return a;               
            }
            a++;                            
        }
    })(jQuery); 
}
```

It alerts two times:

[image]

[image]

Why is the return value 'undefined'? It must be `1`. Where am I missing?

Comment: Because your function `myid_templates_editor_image_id_generator` doesn't return anything. Try adding the `return` keyword in front of the one expression in its body. Javascript doesn't have implicit returns.

Comment: Because you didn't return anything in scope of `myid_templates_editor_image_id_generator`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function `myid_templates_editor_image_id_generator` is returning nothing. The only return statement you have (`return a;`) exits `function($){...}` but it's not propagated to outer function.